# Extending Modules from a gem instead of monkey patching

Tags: ruby, extension-methods

Assuming that "clean" Ruby monkey patching isn't an option, and all gem extension methods need to be completely contained within their own namespace, and given a structure like

```
module ARubyGem
  class GemClassOne
    def method1
      # instance method to be available when calling extended module 
    end
    def self.method2
      # singleton method to also be available in extended module
    end
  end
end
```

Then which of these is the better way to extend a gem if the original gem code has some singleton methods that begin with "self"?

```
module ARubyGemExtension
  class GemClassOneExtension < ARubyGem::GemClassOne
    def method_to_override
      # new code here
    end
  end
end
```

vs.

```
module ARubyGemExtension
  include ARubyGem 
  class GemClassOneExtension
    def method_to_override
      # new code here
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you would need to go with:

```
  module ARubyGemExtension
    class GemClassOneExtension < ARubyGem::GemClassOne
      def method_to_override
        # new code here
      end
    end
  end
```

(Remember to namespace `GemClassOne`.)

I don't know anything about the gem you're using, but unless it's specifically set up for providing methods through `include`, I think you may not get what you're after.

Comment: Ok does this mean that every class I want to be able to access in GemClassOne via GemClassOneExtension needs to be explicitly extended in a new GemClassOneExtension class?

Comment: Is there a way to indicate that a specific extended class or method should just copy the original class or method without changing behavior?

Comment: You don't need to indicate that the child inherits a method from the parent. That's the very nature of inheritance. You can just call `GemClassOneExtension.method1` and `GemClassOneExtension#method2` - you do not need to declare them in `GemClassOneExtension` unless you want to override them.

Comment: But I would need to declare each individual class  in GemClassOneExtension if I want to use those in the namespace of the new module, correct?  i.e. class GemClassNothingNewHere < ARubyGem::GemClassNothingNewHere ; end

Comment: Thanks again jvillian: also... do I need to give the extended (or unchanged) classes a new name?  Or can I extend class ARubyGem::KeepMyName into the new module like this: class KeepMyName < ARubyGem::KeepMyName

Comment: And if I do keep the same name, does that work for unaltered (empty) extended classes, as well as ones I want to use to re-write methods?

Comment: You can keep the class name the same (which is, in part, the point of namespaces). And yes, it works for unaltered classes.